What's the best Latin translation for "Live free or die"?
I'm looking to hang a sign over my door that says "Live free or die" in Latin. Depending on the Latin syntax, I could see the following variations:
"YOU live free or YOU die"
"WE live free or WE die"
"Either we live free or we die"
Thank you very much for your help.

By analogy to aut caesar aut nihil (= "either caesar or nothing" ≈ "all or nothing"), one option would be aut liber aut mortuus, "either free or dead".
This is the masculine singular form.
The masculine plural would be liberi&mortui, and the feminine would be libera&mortua in the singular and liberae&mortuae in the plural.

According to Wikipedia (yeah, I know) the origin of "Live free or die" comes from the French Vivre Libre ou Mourir, which I would translate liber vivere aut mori "To live free, or to die", to be schoolboyish about it. You can replace liber with liberi if you want the plural.
You can also put either liber or liberi into the accusative (liberum or liberos, depending on how you use it:
Dicuntur liberi vivere aut mori, they are said to live free or to die.
Dicunt se liberos vivere aut mori, they said they live free or they die.
In a motto, I suspect that last point may be overly pedantic.
